# "Set" temperature or "setted" temperature?

Tags: conjugations

I'm writing a biology report in English (while it isn't my mothertongue), and I was wondering if I should write about the "set" or "setted" temperature of the machine I used for my experiments. I saw both versions in different articles and I was wondering which formulation was the best.

Thanks in advance for the help!

**EDIT:**

Examples of articles I found using "setted" temperature:

Dae-Young Lim and Young-Jae Ryoo, "Development of remote monitoring system for cold-storage," 30th Annual Conference of IEEE Industrial Electronics Society, 2004. IECON 2004, pp. 2252-2254 Vol. 3.
doi: 10.1109/IECON.2004.1432149
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1432149/#full-text-section

And even if I couldn't see the full texts of these two, it seems like they used "setted temperature" as well:

http://en.cnki.com.cn/Article_en/CJFDTOTAL-HGJZ201009007.htm

http://en.cnki.com.cn/Article_en/CJFDTOTAL-YBJI201010000.htm

Comment: I'll give the authors of that paper the benefit of the doubt and assume their research is good, but that paper is not well-written. Using _setted_ instead of _set_ is just one of many problems with that paper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [conjugation](http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-set.html) of the verb **to set** has **set** (not *setted*) as the part participle, and it is the past participle that you use as the adjective form: "set temperature."  Compare to "fixed temperature," where **fixed** is the past participle of **to fix**.

You may occasionally see "setted" because that would be the regular formation of the past participle if the verb "to set" were not irregular.  But formal English usage prescribes that the past participle is indeed **set**.

Comment: This seems mostly or generally supported, but: *set1
VERB sets, setting, setted* --"Definition of set in English by Oxford Dictionaries" (https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/set).

What do they know that we don't? O.O

Comment: @JimReynolds: That's weird, because in their own example sentences, they never use the form "setted", even when using the simple past ("she set the table and began breakfast") or the past participle ("wait until first flowers have set fruit before planting out the peppers"). I have seen some references that say that "setted" is an acceptable past participle in BrE for the use "to group together in sets," as in, "the students were setted according to reading ability;" but even in BrE, it's only for that one specific meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Just think about it this way. If you want to indicate that event happened in the past, then use **Simple Past Form* and which is set.

**Base Form (Verb)**: Set (Generally You can use in simple present tense) 
I set temperature everyday. (Daily activity)
He sets temperature everyday. (Daily activity but third person)

**Past Simple**: Set
He set temperature yesterday. (Past tense - Third person)
I set temperature yesterday. (Past tense singular person )

**Past Participle**: Set
He has set temperature recently.

**3rd Person Singular**: Sets (Simple present tense form )

**Present Participle/Gerund**:  Setting
I am setting temperature. ( indicate Current activity )
He is setting temperature. (third person )

Hope this clears your confusion.